# consolibyte: Custom fields are not imported to MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks

I am using consolibyte library to sync data between MySql and QuickBook. Other data is being synced successfully but I did not find the **Custom Fields**. I have to sync only two three things Customers, Items and Invoices. Where the Custom Fields are being stored in MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom fields are pushed to the `qb_dataext` table.

Note that custom fields are NOT fully implemented (the code is in beta) so don't expect great support.