# Consolibyte QuickBooks Desktop import tables for Customers, Item and invoices only

Tags: mysql, quickbooks

I am using QuickBooks PHP Dev kit for quickbooks desktop syncing with a MySQL database. I want to sync Customers, Item and invoice data only.
Currently, I have executed the `example_mysql_mirror.php` script file. It created *139 tables* in the MySQL database and synchronised data between QuickBooks desktop and MySQL successfully.

The problem is that I want to synchronise only three entities named `"customer"`, `"item"`, and `"invoice"`. I investigated code so that the script creates tables for `customer`, item and invoice only, but I didn't find anything. I have found that I can specify in PHP script to synchronise data of customer, invoice and item, but I didn't find out how to create tables only for three entities.

Can anybody mention table names which are required for `customer`, item and invoice syncing so that I don't have *139 tables* in the database?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts always create all of the tables. There is no way to turn off creating all of the tables.

If you'd like, you can drop any tables that you don't need afterwards.

Comment: Thanks keith! Can you please mention list of tables that are used for customer, invoice and item so that i can delete unused tables from database?

Comment: One more thing i was looking for custom fields data of customer in QuickBooks database but couldn't find it. Can you please tell me in which table customer custom fields are stored?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924489/consolibyte-custom-fields-are-not-imported-to-mysql-database